# A certain virus infects one in every 500 people

Tags: probability, statistics

A certain virus infects one in every 500 people. A test used to detect the virus in a person is positive 90% of the time if the person has the virus and 10% of the time if the person does not have the virus.

What is the probability that a person has the virus given that they have tested positive.

What is the probability that a person does not have the virus given that they have tested negative.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?  Have you tried applying Bayes' rule?

Comment: Yes I have and I am having a hard time understanding as well as solving these problem. I am on asking for help !

Answer (score 3):

Bayes Theorem is hard to understand at first. I find it helps to consider an example numerically rather than considering it theoretically. Once you get facility with the numbers, you can use the theory.

> A certain virus infects one in every 500 people.

OK, so lets take a million people and mark 2000 of them with the letter P and 998000 of them with the letter N, for positive and negative.

> A test used to detect the virus in a person is positive 90% of the time if the person has the virus and 10% of the time if the person does not have the virus.

And presumably it is negative the rest of the time.

OK, we'll take those 2000 P people and mark 1800 of them PP, for positive-and-test-was-positive, and 200 of them PN for positive-and-test-was-negative.

The PP group are the "true positives" -- the test was positive, and correct.  The PN group is the "false negative" -- the test was negative, and wrong.

We'll then take those 998000 N people and mark 99800 of them NP, and the remaining 898200 of them NN.

The NP group is the "false positives" -- they tested positive, but the test was wrong.  And the NN group is "true negatives" -- they tested negative, and the test was right.

> What is the probability that a person has the virus given that they have tested positive.

The people who tested positive are marked NP and PP. There are 99800 + 1800 of them, but only the PPs have the virus, so the probability is 1800 / (99800 + 1800).

Notice how terrible this is. If you test positive, odds are good that you *don't* have the disease! A 90% accuracy rate in a test is really bad if the disease is rare, because the test is more likely to be wrong than you are likely to have the disease!  If false positives outnumber true positives, then a positive test is probably a false test.

> What is the probability that a person does not have the virus given that they have tested negative.

Now you can see how to work this out. The people who tested negative are marked PN and NN, but only the NNs are actually negative, so its NN / (PN + NN). The odds are really good that if you tested negative, you really are.

It seems counterintuitive at first, but it is really important to understand that *the test has to be more accurate than the incidence of the disease*. Lots of doctors don't understand this well and will make large errors in computing the probability of disease given a positive test result.

Exercise: Try it again with a test that is 99.9% accurate instead of 90% accurate and see how the answer changes.

Exercise: Most real-world tests are not straight up 90% accurate in all circumstances. Suppose the test is 99% accurate *if you have the virus* but only 80% accurate *if you do not*.  Can you work out the probability of having the virus if you have a positive test now? What about probability of not having the virus if its negative?

(Notice that there was no requirement in the statement of the problem that the 90% and 10% add up to 100%, so it is a slightly confusing example problem.  It would have been just as sensible to say "the test is positive 99% of the time if the person has the virus and 20% of the time if they do not".)

But the moral of the story here is: if you're stuck on a probability problem, just go back to an example with actual numbers rather than doing abstract algebra. Facility with the algebra will come once you have the intuition that comes from working out numerical problems.

Comment: Bayes Theorem is very hard for me too understand. Unfortunately, my professor didn't explain it as much it was pretty much thrown at us. But, thanks for showing me another option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this.  Imagine a population of 100000 people.
"A certain virus infects one in every 500 people."
  100000/500= 200 so there are 100 people infected, 99800 not infected.

"A test used to detect the virus in a person is positive 90% of the time if the person has the virus and 10% of the time if the person does not have the virus."
   Of the 200 people who are infected, .9(200)= 180 test positive. Of the 99800 people who are not infected, .1(99800)= 9980 will test positive.  Of the 9980+ 180= 10160 people who test positive, 180 are infected.

"What is the probability that a person has the virus given that they have tested positive."
  The probability a person who tests positive actually has the virus is 180/10160= 0.0177 or about 1.77%.

"What is the probability that a person does not have the virus given that they have tested negative."
  Of the 180 people who are infected, .1(180)= 18 will text negative.  Of the 99800 people who are not infected, .9(99800)= 89820 will test negative.  Of the 89820+ 18= 89838 people who tested negative 89820 do not have the virus so the probability a person who tested negative does not have the virus is 89820/89832= 0.999 or about 99.9%.

Comment: Thank You, this is explain better now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

A key step to any word problem is extracting the relevant information.  Let $T$ denote the event in which a person *tests* positive, and let $V$ denote the event in which a person has the *virus*.  Based on the problem, we have
$$
P(V) = 1/500 = 0.002\\
P(T\mid V) = 0.90\\
P(T \mid \bar V) = 0.10
$$
The question is asking for $P(V \mid T)$, and then for $P(\bar V \mid \bar T)$.  We can calculate each of these using Bayes' rule.  The first is given by
$$
P(V \mid T) = \frac{P(V \text{ and } T)}{P(T)} = 
\frac{P(V)P(T \mid V)}{P(V)P(T \mid V) + P(\bar V)P(T \mid \bar V)}
$$
Note that $P(\bar V) = 1 - P(V)$.  Similarly, it is important to note for the second part that $P(\bar T \mid V) = 1 - P(T \mid V)$.